# Why won't tests for angular components pass when I have a css file attached?

Tags: html, unit-testing, angular, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a component in Angular 4 that has an external template and a css file. I'm using an asynchronous beforeEach to compile the component using TestBed but it doesn't work unless I remove the content of the css file and remove classes and id's from the html tags. Why is this happening?

Here is the spec:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it(`should have as title 'app works!'`, async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('app works!');
  }));

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('appworks!');
  }));
});
```

Here is the component :

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'app works!';
    }
```

Here is the html page :

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1
```

>
Here is the css file :

```
 h1 {
      color: #369;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 250%;
    }
```

[This is a screenshot of the error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLLj0.png)

The same error appears for each test.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been blocked for a couple of days.

Comment: Maybe it's got something to do with view encapsulation that angular applies when you specify `styles` or `styleUrls` for components. By default angular emulates shadow dom in this case. Try adding the following to your `@Component` object: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and see if it helps

Comment: are u using angular-cli?

Comment: Yeah I am using angular-cli

Comment: @Riiverside that solved the problem. Can you please explain why?

Comment: TBH this seems more like a bug to me. I see no reason why the default view encapsulation should produce errors during testing. You might want to open an issue at the angular github repo